# Why Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildClean?

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk, visual-studio-app-center

When i run below gradle.gradle its building with out issues where as in APpCenter am getting below issue please assist someone no clue sofar why this is issues only in AppCenter

```
Configure project :app
2020-10-22T15:53:29.5724880Z Resolved com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4 in :app:classpath 
2020-10-22T15:53:29.5726230Z Resolved com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0 in :app:classpath 
2020-10-22T15:53:44.3531270Z Project app at :app is either no Android app project or build version has not been set to override. Skipping...
2020-10-22T15:53:53.5603560Z Resolved org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.4.10 in :app:kotlinCompilerClasspath 
2020-10-22T15:54:20.8955890Z Checking the license for package CMake 3.10.2.4988404 in /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/licenses
2020-10-22T15:54:20.8957030Z License for package CMake 3.10.2.4988404 accepted.
2020-10-22T15:54:21.2658590Z Preparing "Install CMake 3.10.2.4988404 (revision: 3.10.2)".
2020-10-22T15:55:16.4483640Z "Install CMake 3.10.2.4988404 (revision: 3.10.2)" ready.
2020-10-22T15:55:16.4500400Z Installing CMake 3.10.2.4988404 in /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404
2020-10-22T15:55:16.4501290Z "Install CMake 3.10.2.4988404 (revision: 3.10.2)" complete.
2020-10-22T15:55:19.4852670Z "Install CMake 3.10.2.4988404 (revision: 3.10.2)" finished.
2020-10-22T15:55:19.8868630Z 
2020-10-22T15:55:19.8870500Z > Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
2020-10-22T15:55:19.8871590Z > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
2020-10-22T15:55:19.8872720Z > Task :app:preBookmybasketsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
2020-10-22T15:55:19.9583860Z 
2020-10-22T15:55:19.9594450Z > Task :app:externalNativeBuildCleanBookmybasketsDebug FAILED
2020-10-22T15:55:19.9596220Z Clean native-lib armeabi-v7a
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1544910Z 
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1624950Z FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1649800Z 
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1650710Z * What went wrong:
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1652140Z Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildCleanBookmybasketsDebug'.
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1653300Z > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:Usersveerendra''
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1653830Z 
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1654260Z * Try:
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1655650Z Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1656340Z 
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1656820Z * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1657250Z 
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1657650Z BUILD FAILED in 4m 9s
2020-10-22T15:55:20.1658560Z 2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
2020-10-22T15:55:20.7918810Z Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew failed with return code: 1
2020-10-22T15:55:20.7922980Z     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/1.128.0/node_modules/vsts-task-lib/toolrunner.js:569:30)
2020-10-22T15:55:20.7924290Z     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
2020-10-22T15:55:20.7924720Z     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
2020-10-22T15:55:20.7925050Z     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
2020-10-22T15:55:20.7925420Z     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:351:11)
2020-10-22T15:55:20.7925750Z     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2020-10-22T15:55:20.7926030Z     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2020-10-22T15:55:20.7926380Z     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:509:12)
2020-10-22T15:55:20.7986170Z ##[error]Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew failed with return code: 1
2020-10-22T15:55:20.8017170Z ##[section]Finishing: Gradle Task
2020-10-22T15:55:20.8764540Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout FoodApp_Prod@Develop1 to s
2020-10-22T15:55:20.8772720Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-22T15:55:20.8773110Z Task         : Get sources
2020-10-22T15:55:20.8773500Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2020-10-22T15:55:20.8773890Z Version      : 1.0.0
2020-10-22T15:55:20.8774140Z Author       : Microsoft
2020-10-22T15:55:20.8775070Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2020-10-22T15:55:20.8775510Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-22T15:55:21.3628440Z Cleaning any cached credential from repository: FoodApp_Prod (ExternalGit)
2020-10-22T15:55:21.3723310Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout FoodApp_Prod@Develop1 to s
2020-10-22T15:55:21.3801870Z ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
2020-10-22T15:55:21.3845630Z Cleaning up task key
2020-10-22T15:55:21.3850450Z Start cleaning up orphan processes.
2020-10-22T15:55:21.4941020Z Terminate orphan process: pid (1303) (java)
2020-10-22T15:55:21.5584650Z ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
2020-10-22T15:55:21.5939110Z ##[section]Finishing: Build
```

I Am facing above exception while building app in Azure App Center where as build is successful in android studio.Here is the build.gradle i am using any help is appreciated

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 29

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.delivery.pizza.pizzadelivery"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 60
    versionName "0.60"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
        }
    }

    ndkVersion "21.3.6528147" // <<==== Here
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        version "3.10.2"
    }
}
   buildFeatures{
     //         dataBinding = true
    // for view binding :
     viewBinding = true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}

buildTypes {
    debug{
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false  // change to true to enable obfuscation for debug builds too
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions
        {
            javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        }

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
flavorDimensions "version"

sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}
```

Comment: Check if there is any space in path `'C:Usersveerendra'` or it proper for native library

Comment: It looks like one of your makefiles might contain a Windows-style absolute path some directory on your computer. That probably isn't going to work if you try to build your project on some random build server in the cloud.

Comment: Thanks for the update but am not keeping any path in build.gradle file except     cmake {
        path "src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        version "3.10.2"
    }

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Just faced/resolved this issue myself. CMake will autogenerate .cxx files which contain your local user paths to NDK related files. Thus, as one of the above comments mentioned, a remote platform like Azure obviously wont find such path.

You should also be able to reproduce this error locally on a different machine with a different User.

To resolve, I deleted the .cxx folder from my local and added ".cxx" to the gitignore. Push these changes to remote and it should resolve the error.